# filtering based on three columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this (but with lots more columns, and no helpful "KEEP" column):

```
df <- tribble( ~Lots.of.cols, ~analyte, ~meta, ~value, ~KEEP,
     1, "A", "analyte", NA, FALSE,
     1, "A", "unit", "m", FALSE,
     1, "A", "method", NA, FALSE,
     1, "B", "analyte", "4", TRUE,
     1, "B", "unit", "kg", TRUE,
     1, "B", "method", "xxx", TRUE)
```

What I want to do is filter out all the rows of a particular analyte if the row where meta is "analyte" the value column is also NA. So in the df above, the first three rows should be filtered out because row one has meta = "analyte" and value = NA. The final three rows (analyte = "B") should be kept because the fourth row (meta = "analyte") has `!is.na(value)`.

So there are two approaches I've tried. The first is to `group_by(analyte)` and then try filtering or alternatively

```
df %>% 
  anti_join(.[is.na(.$value) & .$meta == "analyte", ], 
            by = c("Lots.of.cols", "analyte", "meta")) -> df
```

With both approaches I can remove the individual row where `meta = "analyte" & is.na(value)` but not the other rows in the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your table is not in tidy format, i.e. 1 observation = 1 row.

To have as tidy data, you'd need to pivot wider. This is why I pivotted, filtered, then re-pivotted.

Also, it's confusing that you have two things named "analyte" that are not the same thing, hence why I changed the name.

```
df %>%
    mutate(meta = str_replace(meta, "analyte", "analyte_value")) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = meta, values_from = value) %>%
    filter(!is.na(analyte_value)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = analyte_value:method)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Lots.of.cols analyte name          value
#>          <dbl> <chr>   <chr>         <chr>
#> 1            1 B       analyte_value 4    
#> 2            1 B       unit          kg   
#> 3            1 B       method        xxx
```

Comment: When I saw the pivotting, I am like "What?", but it actually works so that is the important part. Great thought!

Comment: haha, the pivotting it to make it "tidy" (one variable = one column, one observation = one row). Then it's easier to apply functions. But this a bit of a confusing one

Comment: I feel so stupid. This df is actually an intermediate result where i'm trying to tidy some very untidy data that I have already pivoted longer (hence the ugly names). I had it in my head that i should filter before I pivoted wider, but then I was too focused on how to filter correctly to take a step back to realise that I should pivot first then filter.

Comment: Not stupid at all! The good thing is that you won't need to re-pivot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your anti_join was almost good, just don't put the "meta" variable in the by = c(...) like that :

```
df %>% 
  anti_join(.[is.na(.$value) & .$meta == "analyte", ], 
            by = c("Lots.of.cols", "analyte")) -> df
```

Result :

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Lots.of.cols analyte meta    value KEEP 
         <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <lgl>
1            1 B       analyte 4     TRUE 
2            1 B       unit    kg    TRUE 
3            1 B       method  xxx   TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first fix your KEEP column, and them filter the data by it. First I group your data by analyte using `group_by()` from `dplyr`, them I apply the logical test to discover if in some row of each group, there is a row with meta = analyte and value = NA, and them I use the `any()` function to discover if any of these results from the test, are TRUE in each group. After that, I just use `filter()` to select the desired rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(analyte) %>% 
  mutate(KEEP = any(meta == "analyte" & is.na(value))) %>% 
  filter(KEEP == FALSE)
```

**Here is the result:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   analyte [1]
  Lots.of.cols analyte meta    value KEEP 
         <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <lgl>
1            1 B       analyte 4     FALSE
2            1 B       unit    kg    FALSE
3            1 B       method  xxx   FALSE
```